# Nested foreach loop in Logic Apps does not apply concurrency control setting

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-logic-apps

In logic apps, I was running thru folders recursively for getting files. So, I had a couple of 'foreach' connectors nested inside another. Outer foreach connector (*when it is concurrency:off or 20 instances*), it runs in parallel for running thru folders. But inner foreach connector which is reading the files was too slow.

For each file, it takes 2-5 seconds. For #2500 files, it took (2500 * 5) seconds in total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have raised a case with Az Support. They were directing to following documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#prerequisites.

Extract:

> The "Foreach" loop can process a limited number of array items. For
> this limit, see Concurrency, looping, and debatching limits.
>
> By default, iterations in a "Foreach" loop run at the same time, or in
> parallel. This behavior differs from Power Automate's Apply to each
> loop where iterations run one at a time, or sequentially. However, you
> can set up sequential "Foreach" loop iterations. For example, if you
> want to pause the next iteration in a "Foreach" loop by using the
> Delay action, you need to set the loop to run sequentially.
>
> **The exception to the default behavior are nested loops where
> iterations always run sequentially, not in parallel.** To run operations
> in parallel for items in a nested loop, create and call a child logic
> app.

I broke the nested foreach loops by moving inner foreach connector and code block to other logic app. Now, we have one plain foreach connector for both logic apps.

It works perfectly at blazing speed with concurrency.